# Learning to manually create jQuery tooltips, but they do not show up

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip

I am trying to manually code jQuery tooltips so I can learn and practice my jQuery skills. I cannot for the life of me, however, figure out what's wrong with this code. Nothing shows up at all. The cursor changes to the help cursor, but that's about all I get.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.tooltip').hide();

            $('.trigger').hover(
                function() {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        $tip = $($this.attr('data-tooltip')),
                        triggerPos = $this.offset(),
                        triggerW = $this.outerWidth(),
                        triggerH = $this.outerHeight(),
                        ttLeft = triggerPos.left,
                        ttTop = triggerPos.top + triggerH + 20;

                    $tip.css({
                        left : ttLeft,
                        top : ttTop,
                        position: 'absolute'
                        }).fadeIn(200);
                },

                function() {
                    $('.tooltip').fadeOut(200);
                }
            );
        });
```

This is the CSS:

```
        #content {
            width: 1000px;

            margin: 15px auto;
        }

        .trigger {
            cursor: help;
        }
```

This is the HTML:

```
    <div id="content">

        <h2>Dictionary</h2>

        <p><span  class="trigger" id="wrd01" data-tooltip="def01">Irony</span></p><br /><br />

        <p><span  class="trigger" id="wrd01" data-tooltip="def02">Onomatopoeia</span></p><br /><br />

        <p><span  class="trigger" id="wrd01" data-tooltip="def03">Oxymoron</span></p><br /><br />

        <p><span  class="trigger" id="wrd01" data-tooltip="def04">Socratic Irony</span></p><br /><br />

    </div>

    <div class="tooltip" id="def01">
    <h3>Irony</h3>
    <em>noun</em></br>
    <p>The use of words to convey a meaning that is the opposite of its literal meaning</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tooltip" id="def02">
    <h3>Onomatopoeia</h3>
    <em>noun</em></br>
    <p>A word imitating the sound it references or the formation of such a word.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tooltip" id="def03">
    <h3>Oxymoron</h3>
    <em>noun</em></br>
    <p>A figure of speech by which a locution produces an incongruous, seemingly self-contradictory effect.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tooltip" id="def04">
    <h3>Socratic Irony</h3>
    <em>noun</em></br>
    <p>A means by which the pretended ignorance of a skilfull questioner leads the person answering to expose his/her own ignorance.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes $tip seems to be the problem.
$tip is not properly initialized and hence the css styles are not applied to it.

Try this

```
 var toolTipId =$this.attr('data-tooltip');
 $tip = $("#"+toolTipId );
```

First make sure you get proper element handle and the apply css.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. a.real, you were right, but I didn't understand the solution. Farhan clarified it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like this might be a problem:

```
$tip = $($this.attr('data-tooltip')),
```

I don't believe you need the extra `$`:

```
$tip = $this.attr('data-tooltip'),
```

Also, the first thing I'd do in this situation is (assuming you have FireBug), do a `console.log` on all the values involved in the `hover` function, to ensure that the values are what I expect them to be.

Comment: I went ahead and changed that, but it's still not visible. I'm not entirely sure what's going on with my code. Thanks for the simplification.

Comment: Oh, I see it. You're doing `$tip.css()` but the selector for `$tip` is just "def01" (for ex.). You need it to be `"#def01"`.

Comment: Blargh, I should have reloaded the page. @Farhan beat me to it :) Anyhow, as I mentioned, `console.log` is your friend in these instances. For example, had you done `console.log($tip.length)` you would have seen it was 0, and thus not actually attached to any element.